# CTCallCopyAddress() doesn't work on iOS9

Tags: ios, ios9, core-telephony

I've got the following code which extract the incoming call, this works fine on iOS 8.1 but its not working with iOS 9.

```
extern CFStringRef CTCallCopyAddress(CFAllocatorRef, CTCall* call);

static void callback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    NSString *notifyname=(__bridge NSString *)name;
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", notifyname);

    if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTCallStatusChangeNotification"])//phone call
    {
        NSDictionary *info = (__bridge NSDictionary*)userInfo;
        NSString *state=[[info objectForKey:@"kCTCallStatus"] stringValue];
        CTCall *call = (CTCall *)[info objectForKey:@"kCTCall"];
        CFStringRef stringRef = CTCallCopyAddress(NULL, call);
        NSString *caller = (__bridge NSString *)stringRef;

...
    CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver((__bridge CFNotificationCenterRef)(ct), NULL, callback, NULL, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);
```

When running via Xcode I can see that the NSDictionary and the CTCall object both contain data same as it does with iOS8. But the difference is that with iOS8 after calling CTCallCopyAddress() then stringRef/caller will contain the number as a string, but with iOS9 its nil.

Has anybody found out if there is an alternative to CTCallCopyAddress or mechanism for getting it to work for iOS 9?

Comment: It's actually stopped working on 8.3. You can't even subscribe to CoreTelephony notifications without entitlement. All these APIs now require entitlements which means - jailbreak

Comment: But unfortunately there is no jailbreak for iOS 9.2 or 9.3 and its not possible to downgrade from these back to < iOS 8.3.

Comment: Yeah, all the CoreTelephony stuff seems to be broken in iOS 9.x